# selective input using scanf

Tags: c, scanf

From an input of n numbers(value of n is known) separated by spaces, 
eg(here n is 6):
3 5 8 9 13 2

If I wish to accept only the 2nd and the 5th number and ignore the rest, how do I do it using scanf?

I found accepting the numbers in an array and using only the required ones a bit redundant, so I'm looking for a smarter alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the knwon number `n` is a fix number (n=6 always)

then you can use the following `scanf`

```
int a2, a5;
scanf("%*d %d %*d %*d %d %*d", &a2, &a5 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
int num,number1,number2;
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if(i == 1)
         number1 = num;
    if(i == 4)
         number2 = num;
}
```

Comment: This will not work as `scanf` needs to be called to get input.

Comment: Agreed as all input will now be consumed.

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf("%*d%d%*d%*d%d%*d", &firstNumber, &secondNumber);
```

Try this.

`%*d` reads the value, but ignores it in the name of good will.

Answer (score 0):

I would read every number using `scanf`. Read not required ones in some `temp` variable and others in array or any variable (as required)

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%*d %d %*d %*d %d %*d", &i, &j)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int v[6];
scanf( "%d %d %d %d %d %d", &v[0], &v[1], &v[2], &v[3], &v[4], &v[5] );
```

`v[1]` and `v[4]` contain the answers from your example.

Comment: Memory is cheap, but that seems wasteful.

Comment: `v` is on the stack and goes away when the containing block does.  How else would you do exactly as asked generically?

Comment: You can ignore certain inputs with the `'*'` character: `%*d`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits: know how scanf works and I chose to do it the way I did intentionally.

Comment: Back seat programmer. Sorry.